# How to assign the colors for the values and make piechart using plotly

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly, pie-chart, plotly-python

I have this dataframe, for that I'm trying to create the piechart similar to the attached image.

| Index | Category |
| --- | --- |
| SE | 3 |
| COL | 2 |
| PE | 1 |
| DP-PD | 1 |
| COL | 1 |
| OTH | 1 |

I have tried the following, it's creating a pie chart, but not as expected.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# assign data of lists.  
data = {'index': ['SE', 'COL', 'PE', 'OTH', 'DP-PD'], 'Category': [3, 2, 1, 1,1]}  
  
# Create DataFrame  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
plt.pie(df["Category"], labels = df["Category"],startangle=90)
plt.title("Observation statistics", fontsize = 24)
```

I need the same color which is mentioned in the legend for each category. These are the color codes:

```
{'DP-PD': '#1E90FF', 'ID': '#FFA500', 'ENC': '#D3D3D3', 'SE': '#FFFF00',
 'COL': '#FF0000', 'GL': '#32CD32', 'COT': '#0000CD', 'PE': '#A52A2A',
 'FI': '#000000', 'OTH': '#00BFFF'}
```

I'd like the following output:

[image: I need this output]

Comment: To create a graph in plotly, the following code will achieve this, `import plotly.express as px;px.pie(df, values='Category', names='index')` but after that, how would you like it to look?

Comment: I want same like attached image, Every category has different color as mentioned in legend. how can I assign colors for each, and that should work even I get different Dataframe.

Comment: Have you tried running the code I commented on? When you run it, each category is color coded.

Comment: Yes I tried, but I need the same color which is mentioned in legend for each category. How can I do that. This is the color code {'DP-PD' : #1E90FF , 'ID' : '#FFA500',  'ENC' : '#D3D3D3',  'SE' : '#FFFF00', 'COL' : '#FF0000', 'GL' : '#32CD32', 'COT' : '#0000CD', 'PE' : #A52A2A, 'FI' : '#000000', 'OTH' : '#00BFFF'}

Comment: Try this: `colors = {'DP-PD':'dodgerblue','SE':'yellow','COL':'red','PE':'brown','OTH':'deepskyblue'};px.pie(df, values='Category', names='index', color='index', color_discrete_map=colors)` Color names are in CSS color, not hexadecimal format; see here for more [information](https://community.plotly.com/t/plotly-colours-list/11730) on CSS.